# SQL Alchemy: SQL syntax error on add with session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm currently stuck with the following error when I try to perform an add using a session with SQLAlchemy.

`` sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1") b'INSERT INTO ctr_status (`Name`) VALUES (%s)' ('Test',) ``

Here is the code:

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, orm

# Login omitted...

url = 'mysql+mysqldb://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}'.format(user=user, password=password, host=host, port=port, database=database)
e = create_engine(url, echo=True)
metadata = MetaData()
metadata.bind = e
metadata.create_all()
ctr_status = Table('ctr_status', metadata, autoload=True)

class CTRStatus(object):
    pass
orm.mapper(CTRStatus, ctr_status)
new_status = CTRStatus()
new_status.Name = 'Test'

session_maker = orm.sessionmaker(bind=e, autoflush=True, autocommit=False, expire_on_commit=True)
session = orm.scoped_session(session_maker)
session.add(new_status)

# Crash here at flush
session.flush()
```

I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong. I'm currently using **MySQL 5.5**, **Python 3.3.2** and **SQLAlchemy-0.8.2.win32-py3.3.**

Here are some of the links I have been following:

[SQL Alchemy - Tutorial](http://mapfish.org/doc/tutorials/sqlalchemy.html)

[SQL Alchemy - Sessions](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html)

Comment: I'd suspect DBAPI adapter. It seems that you're using MySQL-python. Does it support Python 3? Could you try another adapter, e.g. MySQL-Connector, cymysql or OurSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by switching the adapter to [OurSQL](https://launchpad.net/oursql/py3k) and changing the url to use **mysql+oursql**.

I would like to add that it was surprisingly non-trivial to get OurSQL working on my setup for Python 3.3.

1. I had to delete **oursqlx/oursql.c** from the initial downloaded files such that it be auto-generated by Cython.
2. I also had to manually modify the setup.py because it was pointing to the wrong registry path for the mysql_root variable in **setup_windowsish()**. Essentially, the current implementation doesn't seem to support MySQL Server 5.5 nor does it support if the registry path is in HKEY_CURRENT_USER instead of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.